# Private repositories in composer

Tags: php, svn, composer-php, repository

How to use a private pure svn repositories (Not a WebDAV HTTP(s) powered) in PHP composer?

I attempt this configuration in composer.json

```
{
 "name": "my/package"
...
 "repositories" : [
  "type" : "vcs",
  "url" : "svn://10.20.30.40:3690/repo/trunk/my-package",
  "username" : "foo",
  "password" : "bar"
 ]
...
}
```

And got an error message:
Repository svn://10.20.30.40:3690/repo/trunk could not be processed, Your configuration does not allow connections to svn://10.20.30.40:3690/repo/trunk. See https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#secure-http for details.

Comment: Just guessing here. You might be using self-signed cert on your svn server, and SVN client complains about that. Look at this github issue: https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/6948 -- solution there might help you too.